# Растянуть TextBlock на всю ячейку grid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-grid

У меня есть ListBox, в котором каждый Item представляет собой Grid из трех колонок. Первая и последняя колонка имеют ширину 50, а в средней лежит TextBlock, который должен растягиваться по оставшейся ширине ListBox. Как это можно сделать? Пробовал ставить в ListBox `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` однако ноль результата, а ставить фиксированную ширину у TextBlock я не хочу по понятным причинам. Вот весь код:

```
<ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="tracksList" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="50" Margin="0 2 0 2" Background="Green">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="SeaGreen" Text="{Binding Path=fn}" Grid.Column="1"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Может надо как-то подшаманить с DataTemplate, жду ваших предложений.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Установите у вашего `ListBox` свойство `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`
До:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: так стоит же у меня

Comment: @Max, в вашей разметке я не вижу этого. `HorizontalAlignment` есть, но нет `HorizontalContentAlignment` - это разные вещи. Посмотрите внимательнее.

Comment: @Max вы растягиваете элемент, а не содержимое ;-)

Comment: Боже мой, Спасибо. Совсем уже ослеп.